# Sequentially Pairing Items in an Array

Tags: javascript

Given an array, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, what is the most efficient method for pairing up each of the items sequentially, like so: `[[1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,5]]`?

I've been trying to use the `reduce` method but to no avail and want something elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use simple [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var res = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++) {
 res.push(data.slice(i, i+2));
}

console.log(res);
```

With **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method

```js
console.log(
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(function(a, b, i) {
    if (i == 1) return [[a, b]];
    a.push([a[a.length - 1][1], b]);
    return a
  })
)
```

With **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method with  initial value as empty array

```js
console.log(
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(function(a, b, i, arr) {
    arr[i + 1] !== undefined && a.push([b, arr[i + 1]])
    return a
  }, [])
)
```

Comment: Can you explain what this line does? `arr[i + 1] && a.push([b, arr[i + 1]])` It works, I don't understand what the && operator is doing.

Comment: @SpencerAllenGardner if `arr[i + 1]` is  a truthy value then push operation will execute... it's just to avoid `undefined` .... It's shorthandler for `if(arr[i + 1] ) a.push([b, arr[i + 1]])`

Answer (score 1):

To answer the "elegant" bit... ;)

```js
let pairwise = function *(it) {
    var
        a = it[Symbol.iterator](),
        b = it[Symbol.iterator]();

    b.next();

    for (var x of b) {
        yield [a.next().value, x]
    }
};

console.log(Array.from(pairwise([1,2,3,4,5])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) for given `array`:

```
var result = _.chunk( _.sortBy(array.concat(_.slice(array, 1, array.length - 1))), 2);
```

Check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xn30uje1/)

So if `array = [1,2,3,4,5]` we have steps:

```
_.slice(array, 1, array.length - 1)              

      // = [2,3,4]

array.concat(_.slice(array, 1, array.length - 1) 

      // = [1,2,3,4,5].concat([2,3,4]) = [1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4]

_.sortBy(array.concat(_.slice(array, 1, array.length - 1))  

      // _sortBy([1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4]) = [1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5]

_.chunk( _.sortBy(array.concat(_.slice(array, 1, array.length - 1))), 2)

      // _chunk([1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5],2) = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another short solution using `Array.forEach` and `Array.push` functions:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], pairs = [];
arr.forEach((v, k, arr) => arr[k+1] && pairs.push([v, arr[k+1]]));

console.log(JSON.stringify(pairs));  // [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce`:

```js
    const res = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(
      ([b, acc], a) => [a, acc.concat([[b, a]])]
    , [null, []])[1].slice(1)

    console.log(res)
```

The seed of `reduce` is a tuple of two items: `[null, []]`. `null` represents the current element in the array and `[]` is the result.

In the first iteration of `reduce`:

`([b, acc], a) => ...` `b = null` and `acc = []`

The function produces a new tuple, the first item in the tuple is the current element of the array and the second item is the result. In the second iteration:

`([b, acc], a) => ...`, `b = 1` and `acc = [[null, 1]]`

The second iteration will add (concat) `[1, 2]` to the result (acc).

In the third iteration:

`([b, acc], a) => ...`, `b = 2` and `acc = [[null, 1], [1, 2]]`

And so on so forth:

```js
const trace = (x, y) => {
  console.log(x);
  return y;
}

const json = x => JSON.stringify(x)

const res = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(
  ([b, acc], a) => trace(
       `a = ${a}, b = ${b} acc = ${json(acc)} ++ ${json([[b, a]])}`
     , [a, acc.concat([[b, a]])]
  )
  , [null, []]) // seed
  // the result is a tuple `[currentElement, finalResult], we extract finalResult here
  [1]
  // -1 element of the original array was null (check the seed), let's remove it from the result
  .slice(1) 

console.log(res)
```

We can think about the problem another way: we are kind of joining the elements of the same array with each other into tuples. Using [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/0.21.0/index.html) `zip` function is elegant but has a performance tradeoff because we go thru the list twice:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const res = R.zip(arr, R.drop(1, arr))
console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.21.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Reduce is most elegant way to do that.

```
[1,2,3,4,5].reduce((a,b,c) => {
  a.push([c,b]);
  return a;
}, [])
```

Comment: This isn't correct. You're using the index `c` instead of the adjacent array member.

Comment: This doesn't give the result the OP was looking for.